# How to launch appcenter tests for UWP packages via VSTS?

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

VSTS task "Test with Visual Studio App Center" is seemed to support only APK/IPA file formats which limits to Android/iOS . Is it possible to use this task to launch appceneter tests for UWP packages? See the screen shots attached.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems UWP tests are not yet supported on App Center. See the [roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/roadmap), under **Test service** you can see the preview is planned for the next 3-6 months:

> Preview support for testing of UWP apps.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Have already connected with appcenter support, they told me the same .

Comment: Hopefully the preview will come soon. If that resolved the question, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey checkmark.